# Symfony3 Sending a Form from the Controller

Tags: php, forms, api, symfony

EDIT :

I found the $form->submit() method and gave it a try :

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/../../../web/uploads/img/tmp.jpeg", file_get_contents($output['images']['show']));

$image = new Image();;

$form = $this->createForm(ImageType::class, $image);

$form->submit( __DIR__ . "/../../../web/uploads/img/tmp.jpeg" );

if ($form->isSubmited() && $form->isValid()) {
    ...
}
```

But apparently the form isn't valid because it doesn't get past the condition

EDIT 2 : I disabled csrf_protection for ImageType but it's still not valid, Xdebug tells me the path is not valid, but if I try to upload the same image from the same path through a form it works without problem...

---

I'm working on a project where I have this Image entity :

```
class Image
{
    //... Attributes, setters and getters        

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }
        $this->url = $this->file->guessExtension();
        $this->alt = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }
        if (null !== $this->tempFilename) {
            $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->tempFilename;
            if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
                unlink($oldFile);
            }
        }
        $this->file->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->id.'.'.$this->url
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        if (null !== $this->url) {
            $this->tempFilename = $this->url;
            $this->url = null;
            $this->alt = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Which works perfectly fine when I'm uploading the image from a local file through a Form.

But I also need to be able to download the file from an API :

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/../../../web/uploads/img/tmp.jpeg", file_get_contents($output['images']['show']));

$image = new Image();

$file = new UploadedFile(__DIR__ . "/../../../web/uploads/img/tmp.jpeg", 'tmp.jpeg');

$image->setFile($file);
```

It is my understanding that once I persist $image, both preUpload() and upload() will be called, but when I do I get this error :

"The file "tmp.jpeg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error."

Which seems to be triggered by the $this->file->move() part of upload()

I'm pretty sure it is because of the isValid() function from UploadedFile which only returns true if the file has been uploaded with HTTP and is called right at the start of move()...

Is there any workaround for my issue ? I'm fairly new to Symfony (and a bit less at coding in general) so I'm not entirely sure of what my options are.

Is there a way to trick $image into "thinking" $file came from a Form ?

Comment: Take a look at VichUploadbundle. One of the more popular bundle to upload Files in your SF application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while since I did this specifically, but I believe that you have to have a mimetype in the constructor when creating `UploadedFile` manually if you want it to be valid.

```
$file = new UploadedFile(__DIR__ . "/../../../web/uploads/img/tmp.jpeg", 'tmp.jpeg','image/jpeg');
```

Comment: Hello, the solution was to get every single info about the file in order to reach the last parameter from the UploadedFile constructor and to set it to true, in order to bypass the function that checks if the file is from a form or not !

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion if simply adding the mimetype didn't work. Glad you figured it out ;)